# How many patterns there are in a sequence of dice throws?

Tags: combinatorics

I have the set of all possible results from throwin $n$ dices. Like

```
1 1 1 ... 1
...
6 6 6 ... 6
```

Then I have been given a list $T$ of sequences of throws:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3
4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

How can I compute how many of those $6^n$ throw sequences contains at least one throw sequence from the list $T$ as a subsequence?

I mean for example if I throw a dice 11 times as follows:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,6,6
```

Then it contains both 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 6,6,6,6,6,6 as subsequences but

```
1,2,3,4,3,6,6,5,6,6,6
```

contains none sequences from the list.

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm to do the computation? Do you want an algorithm with lowest asymptotic number of comparisons? This looks like a string search algorithm, which has been heavily researched in computer science.

Comment: I was wondering how to solve this for relatively small $n$ like $n<30$. An algorithm would be enough for my purpose. All I need is to count the number of strings that contains at least one of the given sequences as a substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step, you can generate all the sequences of length $n$ containing
$1,2,3,4,5,6$ using the pattern

$$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k,1,2,3,4,5,6,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_{n-6}$$

where each $a_i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $0 \leq k \leq n-6$.
There are $(n-5)\cdot 6^{n-6}$ ways to select $k$ and all the $a_i$ values
under these constraints.

If $n < 12$ then this is exactly the number of sequences of $n$ dice
containing the subsequence $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

So as a first step, since there are $12$ sequences in $T$,
the total number of ways to generate sequences of $n$
dice containing some member of $T$ is
$12(n-5)\cdot 6^{n-6}$.

Of course this is not the correct answer when $n>6$.
For example, if $n=7$, this method generates the sequence $1,1,1,1,1,1,1$ twice.
For $n=12$ this method generates $1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6$ twice.

We can account for the duplicates using the inclusion-exclusion principle.
That is, consider all the ways we can generate sequences of $n$ dice
using the pattern

$$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k,S_1,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_m,S_2,a_{m+1},\ldots,a_{n-12}$$

where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsequences belonging to $T$ 
(not necessarily different from each other).
Also consider all possible ways to generate sequences of length $n$ 
from a subsequence that contain two overlapping sequences from $T$;
for example, consider the pattern
$$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_{n-12},$$
which contains both $1,1,1,1,1,1$ and $1,1,1,2,2,2$.

After counting up all the ways to generate sequences from patterns
containing two subsequences from $T$, subtract that number from the total.

But this now undercounts sequences that contain three subsequences
from $T$, so count all the ways to generate sequences using patterns
containing three subsequences from $T$ and add those to the total.
Then subtract the ways to generate sequences from four subsequences,
add the ways to generate sequences from five subsequences, and so forth.

This process terminates when you add or subtract the six sequences
that can be formed from $n-5$ subsequences of $T$, that is,
the sequences of $n$ copies of the same number, such as $1,1,1,\ldots,1$.

This is a complicated procedure, especially since you must account for
overlapping subsequences and (for three or more subsequences)
patterns in which some subsequences overlap and others do not.
But there are some patterns you can exploit;
for example, when counting all the ways to generate sequences of the form
$$a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k,S,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_{n-9},$$
where $S$ is a sequence of length $9$ constructed from
two overlapping subsequences from $T$,
you can use the fact that there are $12$ such sequences.

When counting the ways to generate sequences from two subsequences from $T$,
it is necessary to separately count each of the five patterns that can be made
by overlapping two copies of $1,1,1,1,1,1$
(and likewise for each of the other six-of-a-kind subsequences).
For example, let $n=8$ and count the number of sequences containing $1,1,1,1,1,1$.
For the pattern using one copy of $1,1,1,1,1,1$ we have

$$a_1,\ldots,a_k,1,1,1,1,1,1,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_2:
\quad 3\cdot 6^2 = 108\ \text{ways}.$$

For patterns using two copies of $1,1,1,1,1,1$ we have
$$a_1,\ldots,a_k,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,a_{k+1},\ldots,a_1:
\quad 2\cdot 6^1 = 12\ \text{ways, and}$$
$$1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1:
\quad 1\cdot 6^0 = 1\ \text{way.}$$

For patterns using three copies of $1,1,1,1,1,1$ we have
$$ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1:
\quad 1\cdot 6^0 = 1\ \text{way.}$$

The total we compute from these is $108 - (12 + 1) + 1 = 96,$
which you can easily confirm is correct. If we had counted the 
pattern $1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1$ only as three overlapping copies of $1,1,1,1,1,1$,
and not also as two copies, we would have gotten the total $97$,
which is incorrect.

Despite all these complications, I think this can be computed in less
than exponential time, owing to the repetition of subsequences from $T$
(and consequent ability to count many different patterns quickly)
that will occur for very large values of $n$.

Comment: I'm sure there is a dynamic programming solution along the lines of my answer (for the problem that I interpreted the question to be about), and it naturally won't need inclusion-exclusion principle, but I'm getting sleepy...

Comment: @user21820 I just realized that the "exponential" factor in the running time in your answer was a function of the size of $T$ and the maximum length of sequences in $T$, which according to my assumptions above are fixed quantities. So under the above assumptions you claimed linear running time, not exponential. I misread that earlier, hence my comment about "exponential time", which now seems irrelevant.

Comment: Yes about exponential time. I still don't like using inclusion-exclusion but was too sleepy yesterday so I discarded my half-written attempt. Never mind haha..

Comment: @user21820 My answer _does_ lead to a fairly ugly calculation for $n$ much larger than some fairly small value (I'm not sure what that value is, maybe $n=10$ or $n=15$), mainly because of all the different ways the substrings can overlap. But even on MSE there have been instances of this kind of question (for specific values of $n$ and maybe slightly more tractable sets of sequences in $T$) for which people were able to write complete non-computer-assisted enumerations in their answers using this method, which is what made it come to mind.